# How to compile this tiny loadable kernel module with gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc

try.c:

```
#ifndef __KERNEL__
        #define __KERNEL__
#endif
#ifndef MODULE
        #define MODULE
#endif

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init try_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_EMERG "Init.\n");
        return 0;
}
static void __exit try_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_EMERG "Exit.\n");
}
module_init(try_init);
module_exit(try_exit);
```

I tried `gcc -Wall  -I/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9/include try.c` but it gives lots of errors...

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in a `Makefile`:

```
KERNEL_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m := try.o

driver:     try.c
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
```

Comment: For those at home, this Makefile instructs the kernel build process to build a module out of a single source code file, try.c.

Comment: `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` is missing..how to work around this?

Comment: @compiler: Install the kernel development package.